# Regex: Renaming files and getting text inside brackets and apostrophe?

Tags: regex, rename, regex-lookarounds, file-rename, batch-rename

my text/file names look something like this:

```
['11'].pdf 
['2807'].pdf 
['511'].pdf
['445'].pdf
```

I want the number inside the brackets (no apostrophes) and rename the files to for example 445.pdf.

I currently use:

```
 rename 's/(\[0-9].*pdf).*/$1/' *
```

But this changes nothing; the name of the files are as they were.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of trial and error led to this regex: `rename "s/\[\'([0-9]+)\'\]/\1/" *.pdf`

It's not clear why to me, but the regex fails if `$1` is used and succeeds if `\1` is used instead - even though perl tells me otherwise when I run it.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the regex question, but here's another take.

Regex is a bit tricky to discuss. There are nearly as many different regex definitions as there are implementations. Depending on what language your `rename` program is written in, a regex someone gives you on SO might work differently for you than it does for them. You have to be pretty specific when talking about regex *which* regex implementation you're working with.

If you just pragmatically want to do a bunch of renames, avoid regex altogether and use shell expressions alone:

```
for current in "["*.pdf; do
    new=${current##??}       # removes the ['
    new=${new%?].pdf}        # removes the '].pdf
    echo mv "$current" "$new.pdf"
done
```

(Remove the `echo` to really do it.)